# Lightweight JS AJAX library

Tags: javascript, ajax

My friend and I have a site (www.rosasecta.com). It uses a lot of Ajax, but it's all by hand, and it's really ugly and hard to dig through. We want to switch to a JS library, but JQuery, Prototype, and Dojo are to large. We just want a small, compact library that can do AJAX cleanly and some basic DOM selecters. Can anybody recommend one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried jQuery? It's not obtrusive and you need only use the bits you need.

Comment: You have not accepted an answer for any one of your 9 questions. You really ought to give contributors the credit they deserve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The selector portion of jQuery, dojo (and some of the other frameworks) is actually available as a separate library, the Sizzle Selector library:

http://sizzlejs.com/

Sizzle purports to be only 4kb minified and gzipped according to their site.

However, with ajax too, I think a customized jquery with only the smallest bits may be the best "complete package".  Some of the other libraries like dojo have methods of building them with exactly the features you want, too.

The default jquery minified+gzipped is only 19kb. I think a core build can be done down to only 12kb.

Answer (score 6):

jQuery isn't large at all, and you can use [Google's hosted version](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/#jquery) meaning many of your users won't even have to download it upon visiting your page.

You requested:

1. Lightweight
2. AJAX Capabilities
3. DOM Selectors

You've practically got jQuery already.

Comment: There's a downside to the hosted version: when SO switched to it, a few users (just 1 or 2 out of 1000s) complained on meta because their corporate firewalls blocked it for some reason.

Comment: True. But that number is sufficiently low :)

Answer (score 3):

jQuery minified at aro 56K is less than the size of a typical JPG file. It will do everything you need and a whooooooole lot more

Answer (score 3):

Zepto.js: http://zeptojs.com/#download (8kb gzipped)

Comment: Zepto.js does not support Internet explorer

Comment: @AlecSmart Yep, it's worth noting.

Answer (score 2):

What about MooTools? It won't provide everything jQuery will, but if it will do what you need, it's very small.

Answer (score 1):

Atomic.js , Size is less than 1kb and angular style , simple js library
https://github.com/cferdinandi/atomic

Read more

https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/writing-a-standalone-ajax-xhr-javascript-micro-library

Comment: This is not the good answer because atomic doesn't handle dom selectors but only Ajax requests, but still I was only searching for the smallest Ajax library ever and you made me discover atomic which is really tiny! Thanks man.