# redirect form after submit

Tags: javascript, php, forms, redirect

I created a submit form with JS simply to post a variable to PHP:

```
entry.innerHTML= ' <form action="eLoad.php" method="post"> <input class="submitLink" type="submit" name="name" value='+uploaded[i][1]+'> </form>
```

It works but in my php i want to send back a variable to JS. I'm using Json but every time I  submit, the form submits to my browser and ouputs the php file and echos whatever JS text I have on the browser. I want to redirect to another page after the php and the JS (json)  in my php loads.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Either you develop your own AJAX library, or use one of the ready made ones (Mootools/jQuery etc) no point in tackling this issue until u do.

Comment: Please use a search engine first. Try terms like "AJAX", "PHP/JS interaction" or related topics…

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like sending an AJAX request and redirecting on the callback function is what you need.
As suggested here, I also strongly recommend using an existing library.

To use jQuery for example, you'll first have to include it by adding:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Once you've done that and can use the library, try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "eLoad.php"
}).done(function() {
  window.location = <url-to-redirect-to>;
});
```

One last thing to mention, there are many useful params you can use when calling the jQuery's ajax function, take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend an AJAX solution. Take a look at the JQuery JavaScript library at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. With AJAX you can load content (and post forms) dynamicly into your webpage without refreshing the page.

Edit: Example code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('submit', 'form#my-form', function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          url: "my_page.php",
          success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have added an example to my answer. If you are new to JQuery, read some documentation and look over some demo's on their website. Copy/paste my example code between the <head> tags on your page. It should submit a form with id "my-form" and with an AJAX call to my_page.php. The JSON data you are echoing in you PHP file will be alerted. In the success function you can do whatever you want with your data.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking here is for async submition of forms, otherwise known as AJAX.
I suggest you adopt an existing library to do the boring part for you.

Comment: how can I include ajax? Because I tried ajax already but nothing happens

Comment: How did u include it?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"> </script>
I have the jquery file download

Answer (score 0):

Visit this [Lightweight JS AJAX library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017780/lightweight-js-ajax-library) , you will need to use ajax as suggested, implementing and using jQuery will be the fastest way, but do go for other options like zepto.js, mootools, etc. Also if you want to build your own solution for your problems do a little research on xmlhttp, refer to this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

You wont have to write a lot of code to do this, but using readily available libraries wont hurt.